# Does Taylor Swift's 'Karma' song even remotely have anything to do with the Hindu notion of Karma?

Tags: karma, culture

Not a Hindu here, but I'm wondering if this new song is getting under the skin of Hindus the way Alanis Morrissette's 'Ironic' annoyed English teachers.  In the song, she mentions several dozen things that even in may naivete don't sound much like Karma:

> Karma is my boyfriend
>
> Karma is a god
>
> Karma is the breeze in my hair on the weekend
>
> Karma's a relaxing thought
>
> Karma is a cat, purring in my lap 'cause it loves me
>
> Karma is the thunder
>
> Karma's gonna track you down
>
> Sweet like justice, Karma is the queen
>
> Karma takes all my friends to the summit
>
> Karma is the guy on the screen coming straight home to me
>
> https://genius.com/Taylor-swift-karma-lyrics

Now, I know that people often misuse religious terminology, but is karma even remotely any one of these things?  Just asking so I can explain to my daughter who is a big Swiftie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, karma is not even remotely any of the things mentioned in the poem. Karma in this poem seems to be simply a poet's fancy. It is not annoying Hindus. Karma simply means action. There is no need to mystify it.

Here is a brief summary of the theory of Karma.

> The Hindu scriptures divide a man’s karma into three parts -
> **Prarabdha**, **Sancita** and **Agami**. **Prarabdha** Karma is that part of
> accumulated Karma which has begun to bear fruit in the present life.
> It is a thing which is entirely determined, and cannot be avoided. It
> gives rise to those conditions of a man’s existence which he cannot
> get over however hard he may try. We cannot, for existence, get over
> our sex or parentage or the color of our skin in this life. We cannot
> jump out of our bodies. As far as such things are concerned, every one
> will admit that man is a creature of circumstances. Therefore
> Prarabdha Karma can be exhausted only by being experienced. **Sancita**
> Karma is the name given to the accumulated karma of all the previous
> lives of a man. As a result of all his actions in the past, he
> acquires a certain character and certain tendencies. These are not
> unalterable like sex and parentage. It is possible to uproot evil
> habits by persistent effort, and plant good ones in their stead.
> Sancita Karma, unlike Prarabdha, can be expiated by penances. And our
> scriptures say that, unlike Prarabdha it can be totally destroyed by
> Jnana. Lastly, **Agami** karma is that which is being created now in the
> present life. Its fruits will come to us in a future life. It is
> entirely in our hands. As we sow, so shall we reap.

**A Primer of Hinduism by D. S. Sharma**

Of course the Karmic arrow is insentient. It is Ishvara who distributes the fruits of karma.

Comment: Nice Answer Pradip Ji!